# Fire an event to a Form.Element.EventObserver using PrototypeJS

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

Basically, I have the same question as this one below:
http://www.mail-archive.com/prototype-scriptaculous@googlegroups.com/msg08682.html

In my case, I get this event observer:

```
new Form.Element.EventObserver( "selectId", function(element, value) {new Ajax.Updater('divId', '/path/1111', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, onComplete: function(request, json){...}, parameters:'...'});});
```

I have no former experiences with Prototype framework. Can someone tell me, after changing the value of 'selectId', how can I fire 'onChange' event on <select id='selectId'> control?

I have already tried 'Event.fire()' and 'selectId.onChange()' without any luck.

BTW, I cannot change the source code of that page. I need to write some javascript code in address bar in this format: "javascript: xxx".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with [event.simulate.js](http://github.com/kangax/protolicious/blob/5b56fdafcd7d7662c9d648534225039b2e78e371/event.simulate.js) as discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/460644/471559).

Since you are trying to do it via the address bar you'll have to first include the remote file in a manner similar to [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742118/load-remote-javascript-files-via-the-address-bar/3744239#3744239).

`Event.fire()` only works for custom events, not native ones. Unfortunately.